# openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions always displays webview (iOS)

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an iOS app that has been working fine for about a year with the Facebook API.

Recently I updated to the latest version of the Facebook API.

What I'm noticing is that when I call openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions now, I always get the web UI, even if the user is logged in to Facebook in the Settings of the iOS device. In the past, I would typically just get a native confirmation dialog.

Is this an intentional change in the API or do I need to look at what I'm doing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is use a different method where you can specify behavior, FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent which as per doc /*! Attempt Facebook Login, prefering system account and falling back to fast app switch if necessary */

```
    facebookSession = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"public_profile", @"email",nil]];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:facebookSession];

    [facebookSession openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent
                    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [self fetchFacebookProfileData];
        } else {
            if (loginCompleteBlock) {
                if (error.userInfo  && [[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"NSLocalizedFailureReason"] isEqualToString:@"com.facebook.sdk:UserLoginCancelled"]) {
                    loginCompleteBlock (nil, error, YES);
                } else {
                    loginCompleteBlock (nil, error, NO);
                }
            }
            loginCompleteBlock = nil;
        }
    }];
```